# add value afterwards to key in table lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Does someone know how to add an value to an key which already has an value ?

for example:

```
x = {}
x[1] = {string = "hallo"}
x[1] = {number = 10}

print(x[1].string) --nil
print(x[1].number) --10
```

It should be possible to print both things out. The same way how it is here possible:

```
x[1] = { string = "hallo" ; number = 10}
```

I just need to add some informations afterwards to the table and especially to the same key.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = {}  -- create an empty table
x[1] = {string = "hallo"} -- assign a table with 1 element to x[1]
x[1] = {number = 10} -- assign another table to x[1]
```

The second assignment overwrites the first assignment.

`x[1]["number"] = 10` or short `x[1].number = 10` will add a field `number` with value `10` to the table `x[1]`

Notice that your `x[1] = { string = "hallo" ; number = 10}` is acutally equivalent to

```
x[1] = {}
x[1]["string"] = "hallo"
x[1]["number"] = 10
```